# flash: play a movie from half way in

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, h.264

Is it possible to play an MP4/H.264 movie in flash from half way thru?

Currently cant figure out how to seek to a time that hasn't buffered yet. Is there anyway of getting flash to start buffering half way into a movie?

edit:

The moov atom has already been set at the beginning of the MP4 file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use **pseudo-streaming**

Normally you need a to use an streaming server which cost $$$ but you can use Pseudo-streaming.

Pseudo-streaming uses server-side scripts/modules where you have the server slice up the movie starting at the point you want to start from and wrap it as an mp4.

[Stream your videos with standard HTTP servers](http://flash.flowplayer.org/plugins/streaming/pseudostreaming.html)

[Pseudo-streaming (another article)](http://codeblog.palos.ro/2008/11/13/pseudo-streaming-mp4h264-video-from-php/)

Oh yeah, I forgot about red5 as mentioned below in the comments. That is a free media server option for real streaming.

[red5.org](http://www.red5.org/)